# Unintelligible error code for sorting program

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I wrote a program in c++ which is supposed to print how many time a certain letter is contained in a word. So I used a 2-D arrays which is kinda new to me, i get 3 error codes which I don't really understand. Thanks for your help!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

void check(char wArr[], int letter[], char search[], std::string word);

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
        //int letter[26] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
        char search[26][2] = {{'a', 0},{'b', 0},{'c', 0},{'d', 0},{'e', 0},{'f', 0},{'g', 0},{'h', 0} ,{'i', 0} ,
        {'j', 0},{'k', 0},{'l', 0},{'m',0} ,{'n',0} ,{'o',0},{'p',0},{'q',0},{'r',0},{'s',0},{'t',0},
        {'u', 0},{'v', 0} ,{'w',0},{'x',0},{'y', 0},{'z', 0}};
        std::string word;
        std::cout << "Please enter the word: \n";
        std::cin >> word;
        char wArr[word.length()];
        strcpy (wArr, word.c_str ());
        check(wArr, search, word);

        return 0;
}

void check(char wArr, char search[][2], std::string word){
        for(int s = 0; s < 26; s++) {
                for ( char i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
                        if(wArr[i] == search[s][1]) {
                                search[s][2]++;
                        }
                }
        }
        for (int t = 0; t < 26; t++) {
                if(search[t][2] > 0){
                  std::cout << search[t][1] << ": " << search[t][2] << '\n';
        }
      }
}
```

Error codes:

```
/home/julian/workspace-atom/countletter/main.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, const char**)’:
/home/julian/workspace-atom/countletter/main.cpp:16:33: error: cannot convert ‘char (*)[2]’ to ‘int*’ for argument ‘2’ to ‘void check(char*, int*, char*, std::__cxx11::string)’
         check(wArr, search, word);
                                 ^
/home/julian/workspace-atom/countletter/main.cpp: In function ‘void check(char, char (*)[2], std::__cxx11::string)’:
/home/julian/workspace-atom/countletter/main.cpp:24:34: error: invalid types ‘char[char]’ for array subscript
                         if(wArr[i] == search[s][1]) {
                                  ^
```

Comment: And your *specific* question is? The errors are pretty clear if you ask me.

Comment: Look at the declaration and definition of `check` for starters.

Comment: This `char wArr[word.length()];` is not valid C++. Your code is a lot less intelligible than the error messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is pretty clear. Your function prototype has different types for arguments compared to the actual definition:

```
void check(char wArr[], int letter[], char search[], std::string word);
```

vs

```
void check(char wArr, char search[][2], std::string word)
```

The second error is due to an attempt to use `wArr` as an array while it's been declared as `char`.